# How to create a function in Python to determine if list is sorted or not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, sorting

I'm asked to check to see if a list is sorted using a function, but I'm having trouble defining the parameter (lst) within my function without using the input function. It says lst is undefined but I'm not sure how to change that without using the input function

```
def is_sorted(lst):
    lst  = []
    flag = 0
    lst1 = lst[:]
    lst1.sort()
    if (lst1 == lst):
        flag = 1
    if (flag) :
        return "True"
    else:
        return "False"

print (is_sorted(lst))
```

The error is that the lst is not defined

Comment: At the point that you've called `lst` the first time (in the line `print (is_sorted(lst))` ) you haven't actually given `lst` a value.  Before the `print()` you need a `lst = [1,2,3]` (or something)

Comment: Just to point out - this function will always return 'True' as argument lst will be overwritten and becomes an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

At the point that you've called `lst` the first time (in the line `print (is_sorted(lst))` ) you haven't actually given `lst` a value. Before the print() you need a `lst = [1,2,3]` (or something).

However, you may have overthought this function. I've added a simplified version making use of Python's `sorted` function as a comparator.

```
def is_sorted(lst):
    if (lst == sorted(lst)) or (lst == sorted(lst, reverse = True)):
        return "True"
    else:
        return "False"

lst = [3,1,2]
print (is_sorted(lst))
lst = [1,2,3]
print (is_sorted(lst))
lst = [3,2,1]
print (is_sorted(lst))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
False
True
True
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to understand error one must understand distinction between parameters and arguments of function.

Useful materials:

Python glossary: [parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-parameter), [argument](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-argument)

Python FAQ: [What is the difference between arguments and parameters](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-is-the-difference-between-arguments-and-parameters)